# Trigger notification when job enters dead queue in sidekiq

Tags: sidekiq

How to trigger notifications(slack) in sidekiq when job exhausts all the retries and enter dead queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a death handler. Explained on the Error Handling wiki page:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#death-notification